# How do I get Jest to ignore the message of an error and just look at the type? Or both?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

```
✗ npx jest --version
29.7.0
```

```
 it('should error if id is empty on input', async () => {
      await expect(async () => {
        return await handler(
          {
            arguments: {
              id: '',
            }             
          },
          mockContext,
          mockCallBack
        );
      }).rejects.toThrow(InvalidInputError);
    });
```

But when I run this, it fails:

```
    Error: expect(received).rejects.toThrow(expected)
    
    Expected constructor: InvalidInputError
    Received constructor: InvalidInputError
    
    Received message: "operation Foo failed; arguments: {\"id\":\"\"}; request ID: (none)"
```

Now, this is easy to fix: just put `operation Foo failed; arguments:` in the arg for `toThrow`. But I care about the type of the error more than the message. Ideally I'd check both. But Jest seems to be caring about the type and message -- yet I don't see anything in the docs that allows me to check both in the `toThrow` args. I can also fix this with `new Error('operation Foo failed; arguments: {\"id\":\"\"}; request ID: (none)')` (I guess it's checking prototype?) but I really want to make sure the type of the error is exactly the one I want.

Comment: adding try catch into Jest tests is haphazard and generally discouraged by the jest team

Comment: That _is_ how - [_"error class: error object is **instance of** class"_](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror).

Comment: @jonrsharpe then why would it be failing the test since the constructors are the same but the message appears to be the issue?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans -- [see this section of the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#rejects) -- using .rejects is the supported way to test async code that is expected to fail. Having tried it both ways (reject vs tc): rejects is far better. Been that way in Jest for years.